# How to construct callback to deal with asynchronous return from API call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have the following code:

```
import GtfsRealtimeBindings from 'mta-gtfs-realtime-bindings';
import rp from 'request-promise';

const GetFeedData = (function () {
    let feed, feedId;
    return {
        getFeedId: function (sub) {
            switch (sub) {
                case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4': case '5': case '6': case 'S':
                    feedId = 1;
                    break;
                case 'A': case 'C': case 'E':
                    feedId = 26;
                    break;
                case 'N': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'W':
                    feedId = 16;
                    break;
                case 'B': case 'D': case 'F': case 'M':
                    feedId = 21;
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    feedId = 2;
                    break;
                case 'G':
                    feedId = 31;
                    break;
            }
        },
        getFeedData: function () {
            rp({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://datamine.mta.info/mta_esi.php?key=MY_KEY&feed_id=' + feedId,
                encoding: null
            }).then((buf) => {
                feed = GtfsRealtimeBindings.transit_realtime.FeedMessage.decode(buf);
            });
        },
        get feed () { return feed; }
    };
})();

const ReverseStop = (function () {
    let stopIdN, stopIdS;
    const stopData = require('./stops');
    return {
        reverseStop: function (sub, stop) {
            function filterByName (item) {
                if (item.stop_name == stop && typeof item.stop_id === 'string' && item.stop_id.charAt(0) == sub) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            var stopObjs = stopData.filter(filterByName);
            for (var i = 0; i < stopObjs.length; i++) {
                if (stopObjs[i].stop_id.charAt(stopObjs[i].stop_id.length - 1) == 'N') {
                    stopIdN = stopObjs[i].stop_id;
                } else if (stopObjs[i].stop_id.charAt(stopObjs[i].stop_id.length - 1) == 'S') {
                    stopIdS = stopObjs[i].stop_id;
                }
            }
        },
        stopIdN: stopIdN,
        stopIdS: stopIdS
    };
})();

export const IsDelayN = (function () {
    let noDelay, yesDelay;
    return {
        isDelay: function (sub, stop) {
            GetFeedData.getFeedId(sub);
            GetFeedData.getFeedData();
            ReverseStop.reverseStop(sub, stop);
            var arrivals = [];
            var delays = [];
            (function dataFilter () {
                var feedObjs = GetFeedData.feed().entity.filter(function (entityObj) {
                    if (entityObj.trip_update !== null && entityObj.trip_update.stop_time_update.stop_id == ReverseStop.stopIdN) {
                        return entityObj.trip_update.stop_time_update;
                    }
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < feedObjs.length; i++) {
                    if (feedObjs.arrival !== undefined) {
                        arrivals.push(feedObjs.arrival.time.low);
                        delays.push(feedObjs.arrival.delay);
                    }
                }
            })();
            var nextArrival = Math.min(...arrivals);
            var delayIndex = arrivals.indexOf(nextArrival);
            var delay = delays.delayIndex;
            if (delay === null || Math.ceil(delay / 60) <= 5) {
                noDelay = Math.ceil((nextArrival - GetFeedData.feed.header.timestamp.low) / 60);
            } else {
                yesDelay = Math.ceil(delay / 60);
            }
        },
        noDelay: noDelay,
        yesDelay: yesDelay,
    };
})();

export const IsDelayS = (function () {
    let noDelay, yesDelay;
    return {
        isDelay: function (sub, stop) {
            GetFeedData.getFeedId(sub);
            GetFeedData.getFeedData();
            ReverseStop.reverseStop(sub, stop);
            var arrivals = [];
            var delays = [];
            (function dataFilter () {
                var feedObjs = GetFeedData.feed().entity.filter(function (entityObj) {
                    if (entityObj.trip_update !== null && entityObj.trip_update.stop_time_update.stop_id == ReverseStop.stopIdS) {
                        return entityObj.trip_update.stop_time_update;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < feedObjs.length; i++) {
                    if (feedObjs.arrival !== undefined) {
                        arrivals.push(feedObjs.arrival.time.low);
                        delays.push(feedObjs.arrival.delay);
                    }
                }
            })();
            var nextArrival = Math.min(...arrivals);
            var delayIndex = arrivals.indexOf(nextArrival);
            var delay = delays.delayIndex;
            if (delay === null || Math.ceil(delay / 60) <= 5) {
                noDelay = Math.ceil((nextArrival - GetFeedData.feed.header.timestamp.low) / 60);
            } else {
                yesDelay = Math.ceil(delay / 60);
            }
        },
        noDelay: noDelay,
        yesDelay: yesDelay,
    };
})();
```

`feed` at the end of the IIFE toward the top of the script returns `undefined` because the `request-promise` call in `getFeedData` is asynchronous, and `feed` returns the variable at the top of the IIFE before it's been updated. I think what I need to do is change `GetFeedData.feed` to somehow be a callback (or returning a promise). I'm not really sure how that callback should look, though, especially since I don't think I can call `getFeedData` in that callback because that would mean trying to access an object property within the same object (which I'm pretty sure is verboten).

The other thing is that someone told me I'll need to change the code that *consumes* `feedback`. That would be the `dataFilter` IIFE that is part of both `IsDelayN` and `IsDelayS`. I'm not sure exactly how I'll change that code either.

In the end, the error message I'm getting is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`. I'm working on the assumption that `entity` is undefined because of `feed` is an empty variable due to the aforementioned problems. Is anyone able to confirm this? And if so, is anyone able to help me fix it?

```
const GetFeedData = (function () {
    let feed, feedId;
    return {
        getFeedId: function () {
            // All this does is take input from one of my React components
            // and return the feed_id for the end of the url in the API call
        },
        getFeedData:
            // This is the API call itself. It modifies the feed variable above but
            // is asynchronous. The feed getter below is what's returning an unmodified
            // variable,
        get feed() { return feed; }
    };
})();

const ReverseStop = (function () {
    // This does some other stuff that I don't think factors into my question.
})();

export const IsDelayN = (function () {
    let noDelay, yesDelay;
    return {
        isDelay: function (sub, stop) {
      GetFeedData.getFeedId(sub);
      GetFeedData.getFeedData();
      ReverseStop.reverseStop(sub, stop);
      var arrivals = [];
      var delays = [];
      // The below IIFE is what's calling the 'entity' property that is supposed
      // to be part of feed and which the TypeError is saying is undefined.
      (function dataFilter () {
        var feedObjs = GetFeedData.feed().entity.filter(function (entityObj) {
            if (entityObj.trip_update !== null && entityObj.trip_update.stop_time_update.stop_id == ReverseStop.stopIdN) {
                return entityObj.trip_update.stop_time_update;
            }
        });
      // Now a whole bunch more mutations happen to the array I should have in feedObjs. 
    };
})();

export const IsDelayS = (function () {
    // This is for all intents and purpses identical to IsDelayN
})();
```

Comment: I guess using Promises is easier.

Comment: It seems you know in theory what to do, you just don't know how to write it and make it work. Can you give us a more concise sample of code? So we can look into it.

Comment: I just edited the post with a more concise version of my code at the bottom @RaphaMex.

Comment: Great but now it's broken XD

Comment: the problem is that you're calling `GetFeedData.getFeedData();` and within the same "tick" calling `GetFeedData.feed()`, which as you rightly are assuming is an async issue. I would drop `GetFeedData.feed()` all together and in `getFeedData` return the value you want instead of making an assignment. then you can put all of the code below `getFeedData` in ` .then` function since it will have resolved. also the IIFEs are making your code needlessly complex for no gain

Comment: @azium I changed `getFeedData` so that under `.then` is just `return GtfsRealtimeBindings.transit_realtime.FeedMessage.decode(buf);`. Then in `dataFilter` I call `var feedObjs = GetFeedData.getFeedData().entity.filter(etc)`. But now I'm getting `Cannot read property 'entity' of undefined`. I think there's something I'm not understanding your suggestion properly. Also, thank you for the suggestion about getting rid of IIFEs. Once I understand this problem, I'll definitely look into simplifying my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of material about callbacks and promises on the net. I think you would get the most mileage by reading about that before continuing onto more things since it's so integral to web development (handling async stuff). Jumping off from your last comment though:

```
var feedObjs = GetFeedData.getFeedData().entity.filter(etc)
```

`getFeedData()` should be returning a promise.

```
getFeedData: function () {
  return rp({ // <--- make sure your function returns
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://datamine.mta.info/mta_esi.php?key=MY_KEY&feed_id=' + feedId,
    encoding: null
  }).then((buf) => {
      return GtfsRealtimeBindings.transit_realtime.FeedMessage.decode(buf);
  });
}
```

And anything that returns a promise can be resolved by chaining `.then`:

```
export const IsDelayN = (function () {
  let noDelay, yesDelay;
  return {
    isDelay: function (sub, stop) {
      GetFeedData.getFeedId(sub);
      // ...
      GetFeedData.getFeedData().then(function (entity) {
        // code that needs to happen after async call goes here:
        (function dataFilter () {
          entity.filter(function (entityObj) {
              if (entityObj.trip_update !== null && entityObj.trip_update.stop_time_update.stop_id == ReverseStop.stopIdN) {
                  return entityObj.trip_update.stop_time_update;
              }
          });
        })()
      })
    }
  }
})();
```

Basically once something you need is async, any code written after it must be written in a scope that occurs after that async call returns (like a callback, or `.then` function) rather then on the "next line" which will execute before the async call returns.

Here's a good article on promises: https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html

Comment: Hey this is amazing. Thank you so much for taking the time to write all this out and for linking to an article you know is helpful, rather than just nebulously telling me to go out and find reading materials. I genuinely appreciate what you've done here and will certainly be reading up.